# Lightning Web Component Navigation Mixing

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

From One LWC I am trying to open the custom object New Creation Page but getting below error :

> "This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or
>   mobile app"

Below is the codes available: HTML

```
<lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small">
    <lightning-button label="New" onclick={createNewCarType}></lightning-button>
</lightning-layout-item>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

    {createNewCarType() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attribute: {
                objectApiName: 'Car_Type__c',
                actionName: 'new'
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure having an object with API name Car_Type__c? Also, check [this](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/navToNewRecord/navToNewRecord.js)

Comment: Yes : happening same issue with the Account

Comment: Where are you using this component?

Comment: @rahul Thanks I fixed it in attribute there is 's' is missing hence there was an error. It should be attributes instead of attribute

Comment: @Abhijeet if you have found you mistake, you should post it as an answer to make it clear that a question is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Misprint in `attribute` key should be fixed to `attributes`

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

    {createNewCarType() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Car_Type__c',
                actionName: 'new'
            }
        })

    }
}
```